# Responsive CSS only Triangles

Tags: css

I have [this pen](http://codepen.io/winger/pen/btFcH) here and I am trying to flatten out the triangle a bit. I am using code from [this site](http://codeitdown.com/css-triangles-responsive/) to accomplish the responsive aspect, but it seems the triangle can only retain that one shape. Any idea if this would be possible to change?

[image: It would look like this]

The goal is for the triangle's width to be 100% of the column it's in no matter what the width of browser is.

**END RESULT:**

[image]

Comment: Could you post an image indicating what you would like it to look like? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
.pricing-table .col .triangle-down:after {
content: "";
display: block;
width: 0;
height: 0;
margin-left: -800px;
margin-top: -578px;
border-left: 800px solid transparent;
border-right: 800px solid transparent;
border-top: 500px solid #d0d0d0;
}
```

for a flatter triangle you just have to change the values of your border

EDIT - To get the results of your image shown in question.

```
margin-left: -2800px;
margin-top: -673px;
border-left: 2800px solid transparent;
border-right: 2800px solid transparent;
```

Comment: This is much closer, but the whole point was for the triangle to remain 100% of the width of its column. This seems to stretch it beyond 100%.